# How to get the Error Message from revert and require on a solidity contract with Nethereum

Tags: nethereum

Is there a way on Nethereum to get the string messages returned from  a`revert` or `require` are executed on solidity contract?

Answer (score 0):

```
        var args = new ExecuteFunction { Revert = true, RevertMessage = "Fake Exception" };
        string actualRevertMessage = null;
        try
        {
            // pretend we don't know this will fail, send the transaction
            Console.WriteLine("* Execute - with args that will trigger a revert");
            var executeFunctionHandler = web3.Eth.GetContractTransactionHandler<ExecuteFunction>();
            // await executeFunctionHandler.SendRequestAndWaitForReceiptAsync(contractAddress, args);
            await executeFunctionHandler.EstimateGasAsync(contractAddress, args);
        }
        // conditional catch
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            // a tx hash not been created because the error happened during estimation
            Console.WriteLine($" [RpcResponseException]. Message: {ex.Message}");

            // let's attempt to get the revert reason by querying with the same args
            var revertException = await TryGetRevertMessage(web3, contractAddress, args);
            if (revertException != null)
            {
                actualRevertMessage = revertException.Message;
            }
        }

        Console.WriteLine($" [Expected Revert Reason]: {args.RevertMessage}");
        Console.WriteLine($" [Actual Revert Reason]: {actualRevertMessage}");
```

source:
http://playground.nethereum.com/csharp/id/1050